# Returning referenced data in promise chain

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

Say I need to find some students:

```
var promise = Student.find({..}).exec();
```

And then I need to access documents that reference them individually and embed them to return:

```
promise.then(function(students) {
  var promises = [];
  students.forEach(function(student) {
    var groupPromise = Group.find({ studentRef: student._id }).exec();
    groupPromise.then(function(group) {
      ...
      student.embed = group;
      return student;
    });
    promises.push(groupPromise);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(function(result) {
   // expect result to be array of students, with { embed: group }
   // instead result is array of groups
});
```

I've come a long way in figuring out promises, but I'm missing something. I would expect the `groupPromise.then(...)` to execute before `Promise.all(...)` could be evaluated. As that is clearly not the case, I need a way to ensure that each `student` has the right `group` embedded.

Comment: On stackoverflow, you do not put answers into your question.  Questions are questions.  Answers are answers.  You can edit your question to clarify the question.  You can even make your own answer if you ended up using a solution that nobody else showed you how to do in their answers.  But, you don't put answers into your question.  Please remove the solution info.  Yes, this is different than some other systems.  stackoverflow has their own way of doing things.

Comment: @jfriend00 Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically theres just one thing wrong:

```
groupPromise.then(function(group) {
  ...
  student.embed = group;
  return student;
})
.then(function(student){
  //this is what you want
});

groupPromise.then(function(group){
  //this is what you do
});
```

groupPromise always resolves to *group*. May add the groupPromise.then Promise that resolves to student to your Promise.all:

```
promises.push(groupPromise.then(function(group) {
  ...
  student.embed = group;
  return student;
}));
```

---

How i would do the whole thing:

```
promise.then(function(students) {
    return Promise.all(students.map(function(student) {
        return Group.find({ studentRef: student._id }).exec().then(function(group) {
            ...
            student.embed = group;
            return student;
        });
    }));
}).then(function(result) {
// expect result to be array of students, with { embed: group }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The promise you put in the array and pass to `Promise.all()` needs to be the returned result from `groupPromise.then()`, not `groupPromise` itself.  Because you are using `groupPromise`, you aren't seeing the result of `groupPromise.then()`.

Remember every `.then()` returns a **new** promise and it's that new promise that tracks the `.then()` result.  You weren't passing that new promise to `Promise.all()` so your results did not show the results of what was happening inside the `.then()`.

Change to this:

```
promise.then(function(students) {
  var promises = [];
  students.forEach(function(student) {
    var p = Group.find({ studentRef: student._id }).exec().then(function(group) {
      ...
      student.embed = group;
      return student;
    });
    promises.push(p);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(function(result) {
   // result is array of students, with { embed: group }
});
```

FYI, this is a bit more streamlined when using `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`:

```
promise.then(function(students) {
    return Promise.all(students.map(function(student) {
        return Group.find({ studentRef: student._id }).exec().then(function(group) {
            ...
            student.embed = group;
            return student;
        });
    }));
}).then(function(result) {
   // result is array of students, with { embed: group }
});
```

And, even a little simpler using `Promise.map()` from [Bluebird's promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html):

```
promise.then(function(students) {
    return Promise.map(students, function(student) {
        return Group.find({ studentRef: student._id }).exec().then(function(group) {
            ...
            student.embed = group;
            return student;
        });
    });
}).then(function(result) {
   // result is array of students, with { embed: group }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that moving the promise from a variable declaration works:

```
var promise = Student.find({..}).exec();
promise.then(function(students) {
  var promises = [];
  students.forEach(function(student) {
    promises.push(
      Group.find({ studentRef: student._id }).exec()
        .then(function(group) {
          ...
          student.embed = group;
          return student;
        })
    );
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(function(result) {
  // now results is an array of students with { embed: group }}       
});
```

I must admit, I don't know why it works. Anyone?

---

Edit: Solutions found.
As pointed out by you clever people, the importance is in which part of the promise is returned. The promise pushed into the `promises` array needs to be the promise returned by the `.then()`. These methods is really just a syntactical analogues of this, but I thought they might be illuminating for future readers.

**Method One** - push the promise.then() entirely:

```
var promises = [];
students.forEach(function(student) {
  promises.push(Group.find().exec().then(function(group) {
     student.embed
     return student;
  });
});
return Promise.all(promises);
```

Not particularly pretty.

**Method Two** - Assign the promise.then() to another variable:

```
var promises = [];
students.forEach(function(student) {
  var groupPromise = Group.find().exec();
  var embedPromise = groupPromise.then(function(group) {
     student.embed
     return student;
  });
  promises.push(embedPromise);
});
return Promise.all(promises);
```

A little prettier than method one, but it's not really any easier to read.

**Method Three** - As suggested by jfriend00 and Jonas w, `.map()` is elegant:

```
promise.then(function(students) {
  return Promise.all(students.map(function(student) {
    return Group.find({ studentRef: student._id }).exec().then(function(group) {
      ...
      student.embed = group;
      return student;
    });
  }));
}).then(function(result) {
  // expect result to be array of students, with { embed: group }
});
```

Comment: It's not the moving from the variable declaration that fixed it, it's the fact that you chained the .then

Comment: Look at what you `push`. In this case you push the result of `then`, in the other you push the original promise, not the one returned by `then`.

Comment: What guarantees order of promises is how you chain them, not where you create them